# Android Studio onActivityResult não retorna

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Eu estou mostrando o pop-up pedindo que ativa o GPS ai depois uso " onActivityResult " para pega o resultado, só que ele não retorna nada. Pesquisando vi varios problemas parecido mas nada deu certo. Sé puder me ajudar agraço muito.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResolvableApiException;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsResponse;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationSettingsStatusCodes;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

import transposte.abibeta10des02.abibeta01.R;

public class CarroFragment extends Fragment {

    protected static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0x1;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carro, null);

        getLocationDialog();

        return view;
    }

    public void getLocationDialog()
    {
        LocationRequest locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(30 * 1000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5 * 1000);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);
        builder.setAlwaysShow(true); //this is the key ingredient

        Task<LocationSettingsResponse> result =
                LocationServices.getSettingsClient(getActivity()).checkLocationSettings(builder.build());

        result.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<LocationSettingsResponse>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task)
            {
                try {
                    LocationSettingsResponse response = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                    // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize location
                    // requests here.

                }
                catch (ApiException exception)
                {
                    switch (exception.getStatusCode())
                    {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. But could be fixed by showing the
                            // user a dialog.
                            try {
                                // Cast to a resolvable exception.
                                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) exception;
                                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                                // and check the result in onActivityResult().

                                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(
                                        getActivity(),
                                        REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                            }
                            catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e)
                            {
                                // Ignore the error.
                            }
                            catch (ClassCastException e)
                            {
                                // Ignore, should be an impossible error.
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // Location settings are not satisfied. However, we have no way to fix the
                            // settings so we won't show the dialog.

                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode)
        {
            case CarroFragment.REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS:
                switch (resultCode)
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                        // All required changes were successfully made
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Ativado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        // The user was asked to change settings, but chose not to
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Nõo ativado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Eu estou mostrando o pop-up pedindo que ativa o GPS ai depois uso " onActivityResult " para pega o resultado, só que ele não retorna nada. Pesquisando vi varios problemas parecido mas nada deu certo. Sé puder me ajudar agraço muito.

Answer (score 0):

Dei uma olhada e vi que os seus métodos de ciclo de vida do fragment estão sem as anotações *@Override*, está certo?

Outra coisa também pra se verificar é que no seu **AndroidManifest** é se a activity que é host desse seu fragment (**getActivity()**) não tem algo como:

> noHistory = true

Que na documentação deixa claro que:

> Um valor de “true” significa que a atividade não será incluída no histórico. A atividade não permanecerá na pilha de atividades da tarefa, portanto, o usuário não poderá retornar a ela. Nesse caso, onActivityResult() nunca será chamado se você iniciar outra atividade para o resultado dessa atividade.

Quando você menciona que **nada deu certo**, de preferência dê uma explicação de quais foram as soluções que você tentou. Isso ajuda muito a filtrar melhor o problema.

Espero ter ajudado ;)